# How to add classes to a specific bean w/ display suite template

Tags: display-suite, theming, blocks

On the website home page that I'm working on, we have 4 call-to-actions.

Below is the DS template file which is used when rendering each of them:

```
<?php

/**
* @file
* Display Suite 2 column template.
*/
?>

<<?php print $layout_wrapper; print $layout_attributes; ?> class="ds-2col <?php print $classes;?> cta-body clearfix" style="background: #<?php print $field_bg_colour[0]['value'] ?>">

<?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- If there's a more link, add a link -->
<?php if (isset($field_more_link)): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $field_more_link[0]['url']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>

  <<?php print $left_wrapper ?> class="group-left<?php print $left_classes; ?>">
    <?php print $left; ?>
  </<?php print $left_wrapper ?>>

  <<?php print $right_wrapper ?> class="group-right<?php print $right_classes; ?>">
    <h2 class="title"><?php print $title ?></h2>
    <span class="cta-text">
      <?php print $right; ?>
    </span>
  </<?php print $right_wrapper ?>>

  <div class="clear"></div>

<!-- And close the link -->
<?php if (isset($field_more_link)): ?>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>

</<?php print $layout_wrapper ?>>

<?php if (!empty($drupal_render_children)): ?>
  <?php print $drupal_render_children ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Currently I'm adding a margin-right to each of these, but would like to remove the margin-right on the even number call-to-actions - so my layout works.

Is there any way I can add an odd/even zebra class or a better way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: I've been racking my brains and come up with nothing...what's a 'bean'?!

Comment: You might want to check out, Clive: http://drupal.org/project/bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend helped me solve this one. All I needed was the following PHP as a container class.

```
<?php print $zebra; ?>
```

I can now style the .odd containers!

Thanks all